# Is there a phrase that means "open like a swing door"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there a phrase that means "open like a swing door"? [image]

By "open like a swing door" I mean both door panes open up without sliding open and remains open like we see in the picture. I am not sure if we say "swing door" or "swing doors", because I am not sure if a swing door is a door with two door panes that opens up in the middle.

> The garage opened like swing doors.
>
> The floor opened up like swing doors and sent John sliding inside a tunnel.

Comment: How about, "both garage doors swung open inwards"?

Comment: The doors *themselves* are described as ***hinged*** *doors*, not ***swing*** *doors*. What they *do* is *swing*.